# Rodar aplicação JavaFX em Android

Tags: javafx

Tenho uma aplicação desktop que utiliza JavaFx e gostaria de faze-la rodar em tablets, alguem tem uma dica?

Comment: Ao invés de escrever sobre o que é seu problema, descreva sucintamente o problema no título. Deixe a tecnologia usada para as *tags*. Estamos aqui para ajudar, então qualquer texto neste sentido é desnecessário. Deixe a pergunta limpa, focada no que realmente interessa. Aí coloque informações relevantes. Uma pergunta deve ter um foco claro. Na forma atual ela está muito ampla. [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe o projeto **JavaFX ports**

http://javafxports.org/page/home

Tutorial:

http://javafxports.org/page/Getting_Started

Android:
Você precisa:

- Seu aplicativo JavaFX, construído como JAR, por exemplo, /path/to/your/app/yourapplication.jar. O aplicativo resultante deve ser no Java 7 (ou Java 6) formato de classe
  todas as bibliotecas que você depende, no mesmo diretório. Essas bibliotecas devem conter as classes Java 6/7 também (sem Java 8 por enquanto)
- O Android SDK, em /path/to/androidSDK. Transferir este de http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download. A fim de ser capaz de usar o plugin Gradle Android, você precisa pelo menos versão API 21 e ferramentas de compilação 21.1.1
- O JavaFX SDK da Dalvik, que pode ser obtido em https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/downloads/dalvik-sdk-8u20b3.zip
  O sistema de compilação do Gradle